# how to do a pause before doing storyboard animation

Tags: wpf, xaml, storyboard

I have this storyboard that starts when you hover over a grid:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="SB_MouseEnter">
   <DoubleAnimation To="0" Storyboard.TargetName="gridNav"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).
                                                        (TranslateTransform.Y)" 
                    Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
</Storyboard>
```

I would like to hover over it for 500ms before it does its animation. How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify [BeginTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.begintime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on your storyboard at which you want timeline to begin (0.5 secs in your case):

```
<DoubleAnimation To="0" Storyboard.TargetName="gridNav"
                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).
                                                        (TranslateTransform.Y)" 
                 Duration="0:0:0.2"
                 BeginTime="0:0:0.5"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`DispatcherTimer` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to wait for 500ms in combination with the [`UIElement.MouseEnter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseenter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`UIElement.MouseLeave`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleave%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) events, before manually starting the `Storyboard` with the [`Begin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190590%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. Try something like this:

```
private DispatcherTimer timer;

private void OnMouseEnterHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 500);
    timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    timer.Start();
}

private void OnMouseLeaveHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    timer.Stop();
}

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SB_MouseEnter.Begin();
    timer.Stop();
}
```